# How can I log directorytree/ldaprecord-laravel commands executed for Active Directory integration in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, ldap, directory-tree

I'm currently utilizing the directorytree/ldaprecord-laravel package in my Laravel application for seamless integration with Active Directory. While the package works effectively in fetching user data, I want to log capabilities to track the commands executed by the package.
I aim to log commands similar to the following example:

```
ldapsearch -x -h RHU-DC-04 -D "SVC_ComAdmin" -p 636 -W -b "CN=SVC_ComAdmin,OU=Service_Accounts,OU=Tech Accounts,DC=xtt,DC=gov,DC=sa" cn
```